# Opening Siri stops AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer, siri

I am currently using an AVAudioPlayer to play looped music in the background of my app. However, when siri is opened in my application it turns it off. I am farly experienced with objective c but I cant seem to get this to work. Is there any way I can tell when a user opens siri so that I can start the AVAudioPlayer again after it stops. Please help! 
P.S I have attempted continuously playing the audio but then siri wont work.

Comment: Do you get an audio interruption notification? What audio session category are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AVAudioPlayerDelegate's `audioPlayerEndInterruption:withOptions:`

```
- (void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player withOptions:(NSUInteger)flags {
      [player play];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You have save me much frustration.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming to this, the `endInterruption` delegate isn't getting called from me when my app gets interrupted by Siri. I had to make the app resume playing when it becomes active again (using a notification).

Comment: [Looks](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVAudioPlayerDelegate/audioPlayerBeginInterruption:)  like the calls to audioPlayerBeginInterruption and audioPlayerEndInterruption were deprecated in iOS 8.0.  I gave up trying to get handle Siri interruptions via these, and am going down the same path as you.